# Custom short url for wordpress post

Tags: shortlink

How can I display a short url of the post in the content arrea like

```
Shortlink - https://www.example.com/abc24g4
```

instead of the standard

```
Shortlink - http://example.com/?p=1234
```

### **WITHOUT USING ANY PLUGINS or other services like bitly**

Answer (score 0):

Without a plugin or service? You can't. There's no such thing.

From [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_shortlink/) for `wp_get_shortlink()` (emphasis mine):

> This function exists to provide a shortlink tag that all themes and
>   plugins can target. A plugin must hook in to provide the actual
>   shortlinks. **Default shortlink support is limited to providing ?p=**
>   **style links for posts.** Plugins can short-circuit this function via the
>   ‘pre_get_shortlink’ filter or filter the output via the
>   ‘get_shortlink’ filter.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you are trying to accomplish.

Sounds like you want to show the "shortlink" of the current post in the current post contents.

Create a shortcode (code below) and add to your templates functions.php file, then add [show_current_page_url] some where in the post contents to display the url.

```
function show_permalink_for_post( $atts ){

        // this gets the current page or posts permalink
        $link = get_permalink(get_the_ID());

        return $link;
}
add_shortcode( 'show_current_page_url', 'show_permalink_for_post' );
```